# How can I specify the color of the kmeans clusters in 3D plot (Pandas)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means

I couldn't plot the figure with the desired colored cluster.
Every dot belongs to a specific cluster and hence there should be specific color for each cluster but as shown in figure, I could not get the desired color. how can I modify the code to get the expected result and a nice cluster.

```
pca_ = PCA(n_components=3)
X_Demo_fit_pca = pca_.fit_transform(Demo_df_Processed)

kmeans_PCA = KMeans(n_clusters=4, init='k-means++', max_iter= 300, n_init= 10, random_state= 3)

y_kmeans_PCA = kmeans_PCA.fit_predict(X_Demo_fit_pca)
y_kmeans_PCA
Demo_df_Processed.head()



fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(X_Demo_fit_pca[:,0],X_Demo_fit_pca[:,1],X_Demo_fit_pca[:,2], c=y,
            edgecolor='k', s=40, alpha = 0.5)



ax.set_title("First three PCA directions")
ax.set_xlabel("Educational_Degree")
ax.set_ylabel("Gross_Monthly_Salary")
ax.set_zlabel("Claim_Rate")
ax.dist = 10

ax.scatter(kmeans.cluster_centers_[:,0], kmeans.cluster_centers_[:,1], kmeans.cluster_centers_[:,2], 
           s = 100, c = 'r', label = 'Centroid')

plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=True)


plt.show()
```

[Kmeans Clustering Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LTmX.png)

Comment: you need `c=y_kmeans_PCA` in your first `ax.scatter()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some randomly generated data and a few changes in your code, i think here is what you want (each data point in a particular cluster has the same color):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# randomly generate some data with 4 distinct clusters, use your own data here    
Demo_df_Processed = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-2100,-2000,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
Demo_df_Processed = Demo_df_Processed.append(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-600,-500,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD')))
Demo_df_Processed = Demo_df_Processed.append(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(500,600,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD')))
Demo_df_Processed = Demo_df_Processed.append(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2000,2100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD')))

pca_ = PCA(n_components=3)
X_Demo_fit_pca = pca_.fit_transform(Demo_df_Processed)

kmeans_PCA = KMeans(n_clusters=4, init='k-means++', max_iter= 300, n_init= 10, random_state= 3)

y_kmeans_PCA = kmeans_PCA.fit_predict(X_Demo_fit_pca)
y_kmeans_PCA

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(X_Demo_fit_pca[:,0],X_Demo_fit_pca[:,1],X_Demo_fit_pca[:,2], 
            c=y_kmeans_PCA, cmap='viridis',
            edgecolor='k', s=40, alpha = 0.5)


ax.set_title("First three PCA directions")
ax.set_xlabel("Educational_Degree")
ax.set_ylabel("Gross_Monthly_Salary")
ax.set_zlabel("Claim_Rate")
ax.dist = 10

ax.scatter(kmeans_PCA.cluster_centers_[:,0], kmeans_PCA.cluster_centers_[:,1], 
           kmeans_PCA.cluster_centers_[:,2], 
           s = 300, c = 'r', marker='*', label = 'Centroid')

plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=True)    

plt.show()
```

[image]